# dotnet publish - infinite loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild

When running `dotnet publish "{projectFilePath}" --configuration Release --output "{outputPath}"`, the build runs but freezes part-way(noted below).

The same is true when executing `dotnet build`.

What makes this issue unusual is that the Visual Studio IDE can compile and run the application without any issues or warnings.

Unfortunately, there was a significant number of changes made to the code-base since the last stable build, since this issue was only detected when attempting to deploy.

It is worth noting 2 things:

1. One of the changes since the last stable build was the addition of an NUnit project within the same solution as the web application. The project has since been unloaded, removed and deleted and all references in the application have also been removed.
2. A number of Nuget packages were also updated, although this did not negatively affect the application when running an instance from the IDE. It is worth mentioning that there are several build *warnings* in the following format:

```
PATH\.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'XAct.IO 1.1.17040.3290' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I have executed the commands with `--verbosity diag` and observed that it is stuck in an infinite loop but not stuck at any specific point. This is true for `build` and `publish`.

The below attempts failed to resolve the issue:

1. Deleted the bin and obj folders and cleaned and rebuilt the solution.
2. Cleared the NuGet packages and reloaded and updated them.
3. Restarted Visual Studio as an Administrator.
4. Executed the dotnet commands in both PowerShell and Nuget Package Manager Console.
5. Restarted the computer.
6. Created a new solution and loaded in the web application project.
7. Restored all the NuGet package versions in the .csproj file to the versions specified in the last  stable build and cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

I am unsure where to even begin to resolve this issue since the application runs just fine from the IDE and freezes when executing dotnet commands or publishing via the Visual Studio UI.

Comment: Please clean your solution and then run `dotnet restore`. Does the restore run successfully or does it run into the issues you are encountering? Does running publish/build with the `--no-restore` flag work?

Comment: After cleaning the solution, I executed `dotnet restore` and it runs successfully with no warnings or issues. the build and publish with `--no-restore` flag doesn't change the results, the build still freezes/infinite loop.

Comment: Can you run the Release version from the IDE?